# Why is the oxidation state of carbon in carbon monoxide +2? Why does its dipole moment point from oxygen to carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, oxidation-state, dipole

Shouldn't it be +3 since 3 of its electrons are being pulled away by the electronegative oxygen?
Also, shouldn't the dipole moment point from the carbon to the oxygen since most of the electron density in this molecule is surrounding the more electronegative oxygen?

Comment: It's +2 because the 3th electron pair is the non-bonding electron pair of oxygen.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30797/how-can-the-dipole-moment-of-carbon-monoxide-be-rationalised-by-molecular-orbita http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32161/can-i-predict-the-preferred-resonance-structure-of-carbon-monoxide-from-its-mole