# How many resonating structures of Carbon Monoxide are there?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, resonance

Anywhere I look, I get 3 resonating structures for **CO** molecule, like in [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25126/what-is-the-lewis-structure-for-co?lq=1).
However, according to the rules stated for drawing resonating structures in [this site](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch01/ch1-7.html), I wonder why there can't be this resonating structure as well?
[image]
Although it will be very unstable (due to lesser number of covalent bonds, positive charge on more electronegative atom), yet a minute contribution of this structure must in present in the resonance hybrid of the **CO** molecule. Then why is this structure not shown anywhere?

Comment: For exactly the reason you have said. It contributes a very minor component to the overall structure. There are an awful lot of *possible* resonance structures but very few of them are significant contributors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said it yourself. There are many *possible* resonance structures but most of them have a negligible contribution to the overall structure. Your proposed structure is one of them.

The major resonance contributors of carbon monoxide are: $$\ce{\!\overset{\ominus}{C}#\overset{\oplus}{O}\! ~<->~ \!C=O\! ~<->~\!\overset{\oplus}{C}-\overset{\ominus}{O}\!}$$

Comment: The carbon atoms in the last two contributing canonical forms are not in octet condition. Isn't that a problem?